# Declaring custom entry-wise function

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have the following code

```
nx =81
ny = nx
start = -3
finish = 3
dx = (finish - start) / (nx-1)
dy = (finish - start) / (ny-1)
h = dx

X = numpy.linspace(start, finish, nx)
Y = numpy.linspace(start, finish, ny)

#define 2-dimensional 4-point delta function
def D2_four_delta_h(h,x,y):
    return four_phi(x/h)/(h)*four_phi(y/h)/(h)

def four_phi(r):
    if -2 <= r and r <= -1:
        return (5+2*r-math.sqrt(-7-12*r-4*r**2))/8
    elif -1 < r and r <= 0:
        return (3+2*r+math.sqrt(1-4*r-4*r**2))/8
    elif 0 < r and r <= 1:
        return (3-2*r+math.sqrt(1+4*r-4*r**2))/8
    elif 1 < r and r <= 2:
        return (5-2*r-math.sqrt(-7+12*r-4*r**2))/8
    else:
        return 0

u = numpy.zeros((nx,ny))
for i in range(nx):
    x0 = X[i]
    for j in range(ny):
        y0 = Y[j]
        u[i, j] = D2_four_delta_h(h,x0,y0)
```

As you can notice, I am using two nested for loops to assign values to the array u. However, this is a rather slow process for larger arrays... I want to make this faster. Is it possible to define D2_four_delta_h to act component-wise on u?

I have in mind a numpy functionality, when one can perform operations component-wise such ass

```
#Using the code above
X[1:] - X[1:]
```

I tried applying masks in the definition of four_phi(r), but there were simply too many errors to correct. I defaulted to this approach as it works - for small problems.